# Spark and Kafka direct approach

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I’m new on Apache Spark and I’m trying to run the Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Direct Approach example (JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java).

I’ve downloaded all the libraries but when I try to run I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.<init>(RequestKeys.scala:48)
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.<clinit>(RequestKeys.scala)
at kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest.<init>(TopicMetadataRequest.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:607)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
at it.unimi.di.luca.SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:53)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which scala version are you targeting?

Comment: @lu_Ferra, posting your sample code might help others to answer your questing better.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code with Scala 2.10 and Kafka 0.10 and Spark 1.6.2 and Cassandra 3.5.

I am using receiver less approach/ Direct Kafka consuming. hope that helps

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns
import java.util.Formatter.DateTime

object StreamProcessor extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("StreamProcessor")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")

    val topics = args.toSet

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)


        stream
  .map { 
    case (_, msg) => 
      val result = msgParseMaster(msg)
      (result.id, result.data)
   }.foreachRDD(rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty)     rdd.saveToCassandra("testKS","testTable",SomeColumns("id","data")))

      }
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
  case class wordCount(id: Long, data1: String, data2: String) extends serializable
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  def msgParseMaster(msg: String): wordCount = {
    val m = parse(msg).extract[wordCount]
    return m

  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be a couple of things.

- You may not have the dependencies properly declared in your project. You need to make sure that you have kafka and spark streaming. If you use a builder like maven you can find the lines you need to add to your builder file here http://mvnrepository.com/
- You will also get an error if the topic you are trying to read from doesn't exist yet. You can create it at the command line with something like

  ```
  bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
  ```
- Make sure that you have the kafka server and kafka zookeeper running.

If that doesn't help, then maybe you should post your main as well.